# How is Podman different from Docker?

Tags: docker, cloud, devops, redhat, podman

I know that Docker and Kubernetes solve the same problem. Most users can simply alias Docker to Podman (alias docker=podman) without any problems.

So what is the difference between them?

Comment: Docker and Kubernetes don't solve the same problem at all though, do they? The key differences between docker and podman are the lack of a daemon running as root with podman and "pods". See - well, any "why podman not docker" blog article for details.

Comment: Some differences between Podman and Docker are listed in https://github.com/containers/podman/blob/main/transfer.md

Answer (score 7):

Podman is more secure and lightweight than Docker. Docker relies on a daemon running in the background of your system. Whenever you access the Docker CLI or API to run and manage containers, you are, in effect, communicating with that daemon. Podman is daemonless! If you execute a command with the Podman CLI, it will execute those commands and run the containers directly on the system. Thus, Podman doesn't rely on a Single Point of Failure, and, equally important, you can run containers rootless. The Docker daemon runs in the background with root privileges. In effect:

1. Podman containers run as a non-root user by default
2. Users can run their own containers, and while doing that, the containers run in a user namespace where they are strictly isolated and not accessible to other users
3. Containers are daemonless and run on top of the lightweight CRI-o container runtime

Note rootless containers do not have an IP address, can only bind to a nonprivileged port and must be the owner of the directory they use for storage.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some core difference between Docker and Podman:

| Docker | Podman |
| --- | --- |
| Docker is a monolithic, powerful, independent tool | Podman has a modular approach, relying on specialized tools for specific duties |
| Docker uses daemon | Podman doesn't use daemon |
| Docker daemon requires root privileges | Podman containers can run non-privileged users |
| It is less secure than Podman cause it needs root access | It is more secure than docker cause rootless containers are considered safer than others |

You can get a lot of articles about Docker vs Podman on the internet.

Comment: This is missing that podman pushes more work into systemd, making the most bloated daemon on Linux even more bloated. It reads like marketing materials from podman, missing all the things that don't run under podman.

Comment: @BMitch It reads like the first 10-15 google results for the same question that also lack detail, but doesn't really read like marketing to me. Could you enlighten the rest of us who don't know what all doesn't run under podman, and what burdens it places on systemd?

Comment: The whole point of systemd IS to be burdened with the running of all services on your ... system.  Given that, using systemd sounds like a feature of Podman.